# Division of complex numbers :$ \frac{(-1+i)^{10}}{(-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{15}} $

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried to solve this division of complex numbers and reached to below answer is it true?if not please leave the true answer.

$
\dfrac{(-1+i)^{10}}{(-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{15}}
$

my solution (first solve the denominator) : $(-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}):$

$r=\sqrt{2+2}=2$

$\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{-\sqrt{2}}{-\sqrt{2}}=1 => \theta=\dfrac{5\pi}{4} $

$2cis(\dfrac{5\pi}{4})$

then : $(-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{15}=2^{15}cis(15*\dfrac{5\pi}{4})=2^{15}cis(\dfrac{3\pi}{4})=2^{15}(-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

afterward I've solve $(-1+i)^{10}$ as follows :

$r=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}$

$\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{-1}=-1 => \theta=\dfrac{3\pi}{4} $

$\sqrt{2}cis(\dfrac{3\pi}{4})$

then : $(-1+i)^{10}=2^{5}cis(10*\dfrac{3\pi}{4})=2^{5}cis(\dfrac{3\pi}{4})=2^{5}(-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

in the end when I do replace them on main problem I got below answer :

$
\dfrac{2^{5}(-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})}{2^{15}(-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})}=2^{-10}
$

Comment: You have the concept right. Probably the only error is that $r = \sqrt{1 + 1} = \sqrt{2}$, instead of $r = \sqrt{1 + 1} = 1$.

Comment: oops! It was a terrible mistake. thank you

Comment: @LeeYiyuan can you please take a look again?I think it's done!

Comment: Looks better now. However, it turns out that there is another error: it should be $\operatorname{cis} \frac{30\pi}{4} = \operatorname{cis}-\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead.

Comment: @LeeYiyuan My reason comes from : $\dfrac{30\pi}{4}=1350$ when $1350/360=3.75$ which means 3 full circle and 0.75 * 360.actually I think that even if it is wrong it should be $\dfrac{6\pi}{4}=\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: That is correct as well, because $\frac{3\pi}{2} \equiv \frac{3\pi}{2} - 2\pi  = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ refer to the same point on the unit circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1: $\text{arg}(-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})=\text{arg}\left(2(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})\right)=\pi+\pi/4$.

2: if $z_1=r_1\text{cis}(\theta_1),~~z_2=r_2\text{cis}(\theta_2)$ assuming $z_2\neq0$ then $$z_1/z_2=(r_1/r_2)\text{cis}(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$

Comment: Following your answer I reached $\dfrac{cis(\dfrac{3\pi}{4})}{2^{10}}$.what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right but I think it will be more informative to use exponential representation of complex numbers.
First of all you already obtained absolute value and argument for the numerator and denominator: 
$$-1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}$$
$$-1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{5\pi}{4}}$$
Combining them you'll get:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{(-1+i)^{10}}{(-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{15}}&=&\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}\right)^{10}}{\sqrt{2}^{15}\left(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{5\pi}{4}}\right)^{15}}=\\ &=&\frac{1}{2^{10}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\left(3\cdot10-5\cdot 15\right)}=\\ &=&\frac{1}{2^{10}}e^{i\frac{-45\pi}{4}}=\frac{1}{2^{10}}e^{-12\pi i}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}=\\ &=&\frac{1}{2^{10}}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}=\\ &=&\frac{(-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}}{2^{10}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$-1+i=\sqrt{2}\cdot e^{3\pi i/4}$$ and $$-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}=-2e^{5\pi i/4}$$ So you have 
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}^{10}\cdot e^{30\pi i/4}}{2^{15}\cdot e^{75\pi i/4}}$$
$$\frac{e^{-45\pi i/4}}{2^{10}}$$
$$\frac{e^{3\pi i/4}}{2^{10}}$$
$$\frac{-1+i}{2^{10}\sqrt{2}}$$